# APK update break app functionality

Tags: android, apk, adb

I need to deliver app updates via APK download. After downloading signed APK to the device, opening it and installing the update, some app functionality became broken.

For example, it shows the wrong alert.
Here `showDefaultAlert` is called instead of `showWifiAlert`

```
mNetworkTester = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null) {
            networkType = networkInfo.getType();
        }
        if (!isNetworkAvailable(networkInfo)) {
            if (!mShowingDefaultAlert) {
                if (networkType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    showWifiAlert(null, null);
                } else {
                    showDefaultAlert(null, null);
                }
                AppCardServer.reset();
                mShowingDefaultAlert = true;
            }
        } else if (mShowingDefaultAlert) {
            if (internetTest != null && internetTest.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.PENDING)) {
                internetTest.execute();
            } else {
                internetTest = new InternetTestTask(new OnSocketListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnect(boolean connected) {
                        if (connected) {
                            mShowingDefaultAlert = false;
                            showDialog(null);
                            initConfiguration();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(mNetworkTester, INTERVAL);
    }
};
handler.post(mNetworkTester);
```

If I install the same APK using `adb install -r`, or run it from Android Studio, everything works fine. Why this may happen and how to resolve it?

Here is my AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.appcard.androidterminal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".AppContext"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_small"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".KioskService" android:exported="false"/>

        <service
            android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
        </provider>

        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".content.UpdateAlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try setting "instant run" in android studio to false, if true. Happened to me once.

Comment: check your manifest file some permission issue

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve] and a detailed explanation of **exactly** what "some app functionality became broken" means. For example, if you are crashing, provide the complete Java stack trace and your code that is referenced in that stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not crashing, just getting the wrong views. installing the same apk with adb resolving this. added my code and manifest for the explanation

Comment: @Rohit5k2 apk is made with Jenkins

Comment: @Jackeykabra i added my manifest

Comment: Are you maybe testing your new APK on Marshmallow and you don't have run time permissions? also post code for isNetworkAvailable

Comment: @AndreyRankov I want to say just check permissions which have not support all devices and why you add permission please mansion with a description in "proguard-rules.pro" file. I hope maybe resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I was launching installation of downloaded apk like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

The app was still in the background, and after installing the new apk and opening the app some activity flow fails. This solved my problem:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```